# Одинаковые данные по месяцам в словаре

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict

Здраствуйте! Пишу небольшой скрипт для формирования отчета, и не могу разобраться, почему суммы оплаты, которые лежат в самой глубине словаря под ключом 'sum_opl' у одинаковых домов в разных месяцах одинаковые. Полдня перебирал код, но ничего не помогло. Я начинаю догадываться, что может это просто одни и те же объекты, или при выборке с базы, не смотря на месяц оплаты, все складывается в каждый месяц.  Прошу вас о помощи: подскажите, пожалуйста, куда смотреть, и что я не так написал.

Вот код:

```
import fdb
from openpyxl import Workbook
from datetime import datetime
from decimal import Decimal
import copy




# Создание подключения к базе данных
con = fdb.connect(
    dsn='localhost:D:\FB\Data\kvt.fdb',
    user='sysdba',
    password='masterkey'
)

# Создание курсора для выполнения запросов
cur = con.cursor()

# Выполнение запроса и получение результатов
cur.execute('SELECT NUM, KODSTREET, HOUSE, ADR FROM ZKP_LS')
results = cur.fetchall()

# Создание словаря с нужными ключами и значениями
buh = {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}
dom = {}
for row in results:
    adr = row[3]
    if adr is None:  # Пропустить запись, если ADR равен None
        continue
    
    adr_without_suffix = adr[:-2].strip()
    num = row[0]
    kodstreet = row[1]
    house = row[2]
    key = adr_without_suffix

    if key in dom:
        dom[key].append(num)
            
    else:
        dom[key] = [num] 

for k, v in dom.items():
    v.append(buh.copy())



    
# Закрытие курсора после первого запроса
cur.close()


mons_pos = {
    'Январь': ['01.2023'],
    'Февраль': ['02.2023'],
    'Март': ['03.2023'],
    "Апрель": ['04.2023'],
    "Май": ['05.2023'],
    "Июнь": ['06.2023'],
    "Июль": ['07.2023'],
    "Август": ['08.2023'],
    "Сентябрь": ['09.2023'],
    "Октябрь": ['10.2023'],
    "Ноябрь": ['11.2023'],
    "Декабрь": ['12.2023']
}



sums = {}

# Итерируемся по месяцам и создаем новый пустой словарь для каждого месяца
for month_key in mons_pos:
    sums[month_key] = {}

# Теперь, когда у нас есть отдельные пустые словари для каждого месяца, добавляем значения
for month_key, month_values in mons_pos.items():
    for adr_key, adr_value in dom.items():
        sums[month_key][adr_key] = adr_value.copy()







# Создание второго курсора для выполнения запросов
cur = con.cursor()

# Запрос на выборку данных из таблицы ZKP_OPLATA
cur.execute("SELECT DT, SUMMA, LS FROM ZKP_OPLATA WHERE CAST(DT AS DATE) >= '2023-01-01'")

# Обработка выбранных строк

for row in cur.fetchall():
    
    dt = row[0]
    summa = Decimal(row[1])
    ls_id = str(row[2])
    month = dt.strftime("%m.%Y")
    #print(ls_id, month, summa)

    
    
    for month_key, months_value in mons_pos.items():
        
        print(month_key)
        #print(months_value)
        #print(ls_id, summa)
        
            
        if month_key == 'Январь':
            
            for ls_key, ls_value in sums['Январь'].items():
            
                if str(ls_id) in [str(x) for x in ls_value]:
                    #print(month_key)
                    #print(sums['Январь']['Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3'][-1]['sum_opl'] )
                    #print( month_key, ls_key, ls_id,  summa)
                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])
                    if month == '01.2023':
                        sums['Январь'][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'] += summa
                        print('Л/с =', ls_id, 'Дата', month, sums[month_key]['Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3'][-1]['sum_opl'])

                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])

                  
                else:
                    continue      

                
        elif month_key == 'Февраль':
               
            for ls_key, ls_value in sums['Февраль'].items():
            
                if str(ls_id) in [str(x) for x in ls_value]:
                    #print(ls_key, ls_id, ls_value, summa)
                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])
                    if month == '02.2023':
                        sums['Февраль'][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'] += summa
                        print('Л/с =', ls_id, 'Дата', month, sums[month_key]['Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3'][-1]['sum_opl'])

                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])

                  
                else:
                    continue      

        elif month_key == 'Март':
               
            for ls_key, ls_value in sums['Март'].items():
            
                if str(ls_id) in [str(x) for x in ls_value]:
                    #print(ls_key, ls_id, ls_value, summa)
                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])
                    if month == '03.2023':
                        sums['Март'][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'] += summa
                        print('Л/с =', ls_id, 'Дата', month, sums[month_key]['Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3'][-1]['sum_opl'])

                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])

                  
                else:
                    continue      
        elif month_key == 'Апрель':
               
            for ls_key, ls_value in sums['Апрель'].items():
            
                if str(ls_id) in [str(x) for x in ls_value]:
                    #print(ls_key, ls_id, ls_value, summa)
                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])
                    if month == '04.2023':
                        sums['Апрель'][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'] += summa
                        print('Л/с =', ls_id, 'Дата', month, sums[month_key]['Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3'][-1]['sum_opl'])

                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])

                  
                else:
                    continue      


        elif month_key == 'Май':
               
            for ls_key, ls_value in sums['Май'].items():
            
                if str(ls_id) in [str(x) for x in ls_value]:
                    #print(ls_key, ls_id, ls_value, summa)
                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])
                    if month == '05.2023':
                        sums['Май'][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'] += summa
                        print('Л/с =', ls_id, 'Дата', month, sums[month_key]['Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3'][-1]['sum_opl'])

                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])

                  
                else:
                    continue      

        elif month_key == 'Июнь':
               
            for ls_key, ls_value in sums['Июнь'].items():
            
                if str(ls_id) in [str(x) for x in ls_value]:
                    #print(ls_key, ls_id, ls_value, summa)
                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])
                    if month == '06.2023':
                        sums['Июнь'][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'] += summa
                        print('Л/с =', ls_id, 'Дата', month, sums[month_key]['Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3'][-1]['sum_opl'])

                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])

                  
                else:
                    continue      

    
        elif month_key == 'Июль':
               
            for ls_key, ls_value in sums['Июль'].items():
            
                if str(ls_id) in [str(x) for x in ls_value]:
                    #print(ls_key, ls_id, ls_value, summa)
                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])
                   if month == '07.2023':
                        sums['Июль'][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'] += summa
                        print('Л/с =', ls_id, 'Дата', month, sums[month_key]['Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3'][-1]['sum_opl'])
                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])

                  
                else:
                    continue      

        elif month_key == 'Август':
               
            for ls_key, ls_value in sums['Август'].items():
            
                if str(ls_id) in [str(x) for x in ls_value]:
                    #print(ls_key, ls_id, ls_value, summa)
                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])
                    if month == '08.2023':
                        sums['Август'][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'] += summa
                        print('Л/с =', ls_id, 'Дата', month, sums[month_key]['Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3'][-1]['sum_opl'])
                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])

                  
                else:
                    continue      

        elif month_key == 'Сентябрь':
               
            for ls_key, ls_value in sums['Сентябрь'].items():
            
                if str(ls_id) in [str(x) for x in ls_value]:
                    #print(ls_key, ls_id, ls_value, summa)
                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])
                    if month == '09.2023':
                        sums['Сентябрь'][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'] += summa
                        print('Л/с =', ls_id, 'Дата', month, sums[month_key]['Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3'][-1]['sum_opl'])
                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])

                  
                else:
                    continue                          

        elif month_key == 'Октябрь':
               
            for ls_key, ls_value in sums['Октябрь'].items():
            
                if str(ls_id) in [str(x) for x in ls_value]:
                    #print(ls_key, ls_id, ls_value, summa)
                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])
                    if month == '10.2023':
                        sums['Октябрь'][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'] += summa
                        print('Л/с =', ls_id, 'Дата', month, sums[month_key]['Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3'][-1]['sum_opl'])
                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])

                  
                else:
                    continue      
        elif month_key == 'Ноябрь':
               
            for ls_key, ls_value in sums['Ноябрь'].items():
            
                if str(ls_id) in [str(x) for x in ls_value]:
                    #print(ls_key, ls_id, ls_value, summa)
                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])
                    if month == '11.2023':
                        sums['Ноябрь'][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'] += summa
                        print('Л/с =', ls_id, 'Дата', month, sums[month_key]['Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3'][-1]['sum_opl'])
                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])

                  
                else:
                    continue      

        elif month_key == 'Декабрь':
               
            for ls_key, ls_value in sums['Декабрь'].items():
            
                if str(ls_id) in [str(x) for x in ls_value]:
                    #print(ls_key, ls_id, ls_value, summa)
                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])
                    if month == '12.2023':
                        sums['Декабрь'][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'] += summa
                        print('Л/с =', ls_id, 'Дата', month, sums[month_key]['Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3'][-1]['sum_opl'])
                    #print(sums[month_key][ls_key][-1]['sum_opl'])

                  
                else:
                    continue      
        else:
            print("опа ошибки в базе")

    
                 
                  
                    

         
with open('8132output.txt', 'w') as file:
    for key, value in sums.items():
        file.write(f"{key}:\n")
        for sub_key, sub_value in value.items():
            file.write(f"  {sub_key}: {sub_value}\n")

# Закрытие соединения с базой данных
cur.close()
con.close()
```

извините за обильное количество принтов: я пытался отладить код

Вот вывод:

```
Январь:
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3: ['813', '821', '817', '814', '818', '812', '816', '811', '820', '815', '822', '819', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('36711.26')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 7: ['3050', '3051', '3053', '3054', '3055', '3059', '3052', '3057', '3056', '3060', '3058', '3061', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 9: ['4033', '4023', '4032', '4024', '4025', '4026', '4027', '4028', '4034', '4029', '4030', '4031', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 11: ['6000', '6001', '6002', '6003', '6004', '6005', '6006', '6007', '6281', '6008', '6009', '6010', '6011', '6012', '6013', '6014', '6015', '6016', '6017', '6018', '6019', '6020', '6021', '6022', '6023', '6024', '6025', '6026', '6027', '6028', '6029', '6030', '6031', '6032', '6033', '6034', '6035', '6036', '6037', '6038', '6039', '6040', '6041', '6042', '6043', '6044', '6045', '6046', '6047', '6048', '6049', '6050', '6051', '6052', '6053', '6054', '6055', '6056', '6057', '6058', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]

Февраль:
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3: ['813', '821', '817', '814', '818', '812', '816', '811', '820', '815', '822', '819', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('36711.26')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 7: ['3050', '3051', '3053', '3054', '3055', '3059', '3052', '3057', '3056', '3060', '3058', '3061', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 9: ['4033', '4023', '4032', '4024', '4025', '4026', '4027', '4028', '4034', '4029', '4030', '4031', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 11: ['6000', '6001', '6002', '6003', '6004', '6005', '6006', '6007', '6281', '6008', '6009', '6010', '6011', '6012', '6013', '6014', '6015', '6016', '6017', '6018', '6019', '6020', '6021', '6022', '6023', '6024', '6025', '6026', '6027', '6028', '6029', '6030', '6031', '6032', '6033', '6034', '6035', '6036', '6037', '6038', '6039', '6040', '6041', '6042', '6043', '6044', '6045', '6046', '6047', '6048', '6049', '6050', '6051', '6052', '6053', '6054', '6055', '6056', '6057', '6058', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]

Март:
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3: ['813', '821', '817', '814', '818', '812', '816', '811', '820', '815', '822', '819', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('36711.26')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 7: ['3050', '3051', '3053', '3054', '3055', '3059', '3052', '3057', '3056', '3060', '3058', '3061', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 9: ['4033', '4023', '4032', '4024', '4025', '4026', '4027', '4028', '4034', '4029', '4030', '4031', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 11: ['6000', '6001', '6002', '6003', '6004', '6005', '6006', '6007', '6281', '6008', '6009', '6010', '6011', '6012', '6013', '6014', '6015', '6016', '6017', '6018', '6019', '6020', '6021', '6022', '6023', '6024', '6025', '6026', '6027', '6028', '6029', '6030', '6031', '6032', '6033', '6034', '6035', '6036', '6037', '6038', '6039', '6040', '6041', '6042', '6043', '6044', '6045', '6046', '6047', '6048', '6049', '6050', '6051', '6052', '6053', '6054', '6055', '6056', '6057', '6058', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]

Апрель:
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3: ['813', '821', '817', '814', '818', '812', '816', '811', '820', '815', '822', '819', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('36711.26')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 7: ['3050', '3051', '3053', '3054', '3055', '3059', '3052', '3057', '3056', '3060', '3058', '3061', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 9: ['4033', '4023', '4032', '4024', '4025', '4026', '4027', '4028', '4034', '4029', '4030', '4031', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 11: ['6000', '6001', '6002', '6003', '6004', '6005', '6006', '6007', '6281', '6008', '6009', '6010', '6011', '6012', '6013', '6014', '6015', '6016', '6017', '6018', '6019', '6020', '6021', '6022', '6023', '6024', '6025', '6026', '6027', '6028', '6029', '6030', '6031', '6032', '6033', '6034', '6035', '6036', '6037', '6038', '6039', '6040', '6041', '6042', '6043', '6044', '6045', '6046', '6047', '6048', '6049', '6050', '6051', '6052', '6053', '6054', '6055', '6056', '6057', '6058', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]

Май:
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3: ['813', '821', '817', '814', '818', '812', '816', '811', '820', '815', '822', '819', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('36711.26')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 7: ['3050', '3051', '3053', '3054', '3055', '3059', '3052', '3057', '3056', '3060', '3058', '3061', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 9: ['4033', '4023', '4032', '4024', '4025', '4026', '4027', '4028', '4034', '4029', '4030', '4031', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 11: ['6000', '6001', '6002', '6003', '6004', '6005', '6006', '6007', '6281', '6008', '6009', '6010', '6011', '6012', '6013', '6014', '6015', '6016', '6017', '6018', '6019', '6020', '6021', '6022', '6023', '6024', '6025', '6026', '6027', '6028', '6029', '6030', '6031', '6032', '6033', '6034', '6035', '6036', '6037', '6038', '6039', '6040', '6041', '6042', '6043', '6044', '6045', '6046', '6047', '6048', '6049', '6050', '6051', '6052', '6053', '6054', '6055', '6056', '6057', '6058', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]

Июнь:
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3: ['813', '821', '817', '814', '818', '812', '816', '811', '820', '815', '822', '819', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('36711.26')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 7: ['3050', '3051', '3053', '3054', '3055', '3059', '3052', '3057', '3056', '3060', '3058', '3061', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 9: ['4033', '4023', '4032', '4024', '4025', '4026', '4027', '4028', '4034', '4029', '4030', '4031', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 11: ['6000', '6001', '6002', '6003', '6004', '6005', '6006', '6007', '6281', '6008', '6009', '6010', '6011', '6012', '6013', '6014', '6015', '6016', '6017', '6018', '6019', '6020', '6021', '6022', '6023', '6024', '6025', '6026', '6027', '6028', '6029', '6030', '6031', '6032', '6033', '6034', '6035', '6036', '6037', '6038', '6039', '6040', '6041', '6042', '6043', '6044', '6045', '6046', '6047', '6048', '6049', '6050', '6051', '6052', '6053', '6054', '6055', '6056', '6057', '6058', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]

Июль:
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3: ['813', '821', '817', '814', '818', '812', '816', '811', '820', '815', '822', '819', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('36711.26')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 7: ['3050', '3051', '3053', '3054', '3055', '3059', '3052', '3057', '3056', '3060', '3058', '3061', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 9: ['4033', '4023', '4032', '4024', '4025', '4026', '4027', '4028', '4034', '4029', '4030', '4031', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 11: ['6000', '6001', '6002', '6003', '6004', '6005', '6006', '6007', '6281', '6008', '6009', '6010', '6011', '6012', '6013', '6014', '6015', '6016', '6017', '6018', '6019', '6020', '6021', '6022', '6023', '6024', '6025', '6026', '6027', '6028', '6029', '6030', '6031', '6032', '6033', '6034', '6035', '6036', '6037', '6038', '6039', '6040', '6041', '6042', '6043', '6044', '6045', '6046', '6047', '6048', '6049', '6050', '6051', '6052', '6053', '6054', '6055', '6056', '6057', '6058', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]

Август:
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3: ['813', '821', '817', '814', '818', '812', '816', '811', '820', '815', '822', '819', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('36711.26')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 7: ['3050', '3051', '3053', '3054', '3055', '3059', '3052', '3057', '3056', '3060', '3058', '3061', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 9: ['4033', '4023', '4032', '4024', '4025', '4026', '4027', '4028', '4034', '4029', '4030', '4031', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 11: ['6000', '6001', '6002', '6003', '6004', '6005', '6006', '6007', '6281', '6008', '6009', '6010', '6011', '6012', '6013', '6014', '6015', '6016', '6017', '6018', '6019', '6020', '6021', '6022', '6023', '6024', '6025', '6026', '6027', '6028', '6029', '6030', '6031', '6032', '6033', '6034', '6035', '6036', '6037', '6038', '6039', '6040', '6041', '6042', '6043', '6044', '6045', '6046', '6047', '6048', '6049', '6050', '6051', '6052', '6053', '6054', '6055', '6056', '6057', '6058', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]

Сентябрь:
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3: ['813', '821', '817', '814', '818', '812', '816', '811', '820', '815', '822', '819', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('36711.26')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 7: ['3050', '3051', '3053', '3054', '3055', '3059', '3052', '3057', '3056', '3060', '3058', '3061', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 9: ['4033', '4023', '4032', '4024', '4025', '4026', '4027', '4028', '4034', '4029', '4030', '4031', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 11: ['6000', '6001', '6002', '6003', '6004', '6005', '6006', '6007', '6281', '6008', '6009', '6010', '6011', '6012', '6013', '6014', '6015', '6016', '6017', '6018', '6019', '6020', '6021', '6022', '6023', '6024', '6025', '6026', '6027', '6028', '6029', '6030', '6031', '6032', '6033', '6034', '6035', '6036', '6037', '6038', '6039', '6040', '6041', '6042', '6043', '6044', '6045', '6046', '6047', '6048', '6049', '6050', '6051', '6052', '6053', '6054', '6055', '6056', '6057', '6058', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]

Октябрь:
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3: ['813', '821', '817', '814', '818', '812', '816', '811', '820', '815', '822', '819', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('36711.26')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 7: ['3050', '3051', '3053', '3054', '3055', '3059', '3052', '3057', '3056', '3060', '3058', '3061', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 9: ['4033', '4023', '4032', '4024', '4025', '4026', '4027', '4028', '4034', '4029', '4030', '4031', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 11: ['6000', '6001', '6002', '6003', '6004', '6005', '6006', '6007', '6281', '6008', '6009', '6010', '6011', '6012', '6013', '6014', '6015', '6016', '6017', '6018', '6019', '6020', '6021', '6022', '6023', '6024', '6025', '6026', '6027', '6028', '6029', '6030', '6031', '6032', '6033', '6034', '6035', '6036', '6037', '6038', '6039', '6040', '6041', '6042', '6043', '6044', '6045', '6046', '6047', '6048', '6049', '6050', '6051', '6052', '6053', '6054', '6055', '6056', '6057', '6058', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]

Ноябрь:
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3: ['813', '821', '817', '814', '818', '812', '816', '811', '820', '815', '822', '819', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('36711.26')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 7: ['3050', '3051', '3053', '3054', '3055', '3059', '3052', '3057', '3056', '3060', '3058', '3061', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 9: ['4033', '4023', '4032', '4024', '4025', '4026', '4027', '4028', '4034', '4029', '4030', '4031', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 11: ['6000', '6001', '6002', '6003', '6004', '6005', '6006', '6007', '6281', '6008', '6009', '6010', '6011', '6012', '6013', '6014', '6015', '6016', '6017', '6018', '6019', '6020', '6021', '6022', '6023', '6024', '6025', '6026', '6027', '6028', '6029', '6030', '6031', '6032', '6033', '6034', '6035', '6036', '6037', '6038', '6039', '6040', '6041', '6042', '6043', '6044', '6045', '6046', '6047', '6048', '6049', '6050', '6051', '6052', '6053', '6054', '6055', '6056', '6057', '6058', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]

Декабрь:
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 3: ['813', '821', '817', '814', '818', '812', '816', '811', '820', '815', '822', '819', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('36711.26')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 7: ['3050', '3051', '3053', '3054', '3055', '3059', '3052', '3057', '3056', '3060', '3058', '3061', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 9: ['4033', '4023', '4032', '4024', '4025', '4026', '4027', '4028', '4034', '4029', '4030', '4031', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
  Л.ЧАЙКИНОЙ УЛ 11: ['6000', '6001', '6002', '6003', '6004', '6005', '6006', '6007', '6281', '6008', '6009', '6010', '6011', '6012', '6013', '6014', '6015', '6016', '6017', '6018', '6019', '6020', '6021', '6022', '6023', '6024', '6025', '6026', '6027', '6028', '6029', '6030', '6031', '6032', '6033', '6034', '6035', '6036', '6037', '6038', '6039', '6040', '6041', '6042', '6043', '6044', '6045', '6046', '6047', '6048', '6049', '6050', '6051', '6052', '6053', '6054', '6055', '6056', '6057', '6058', {'sum_nach': Decimal('0.0'), 'sum_opl': Decimal('0.0')}]
```

как видите, значения в разных месяцах одинаковы.

Comment: `elif` для каждого месяца отдельно? Кому же это хочется писать и кому же это хочется читать?